# This is a section of code from a larger function, but I don’t understand what this part does can anyone explain?

Tags: r

This is the portion of code, I believe that it’s doing something within the column range of 2 to 800 from df but I’m not sure.
`substr(names(df)[2:800],1,2)`

Comment: It returns 1st two characters of column name for column number 2 to 800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you break this down into small individual steps it will be easier for you to understand.

Let's take `mtcars` as an example here -

`names(mtcars)` returns all the column names of the dataframe

```
names(mtcars)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

Next `2:800` subset names of columns number 2 to 800. Here we can take 2 to 6.

```
names(mtcars)[2:6]
#[1] "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"
```

`substr` returns first two characters of these column names

```
substr(names(mtcars)[2:6], 1, 2)
#[1] "cy" "di" "hp" "dr" "wt"
```